# Assembly variables

Tags: variables, assembly

I am new to assembly and am confused how some variables magically obtain values from nowhere, like in this code I have (program shifts by one ASCII code all entered symbols)

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
 Enterr  db 10, 13, "$"
 buffer db 255
 number db ?
 symb   db 255 dup (?)

.code
 START:
MOV ax, @data       
MOV ds, ax          

MOV     ah, 10      
MOV     dx, offset buffer
INT 21h

    MOV     ah, 9           
MOV     dx, offset ENTERR       
INT 21h

    MOV     bx, offset symb     
MOV     cl, number          
MOV     ch, 0           

CMP     cx, 0
JE      terminate           

 cycle: 
INC byte ptr [bx]       
INC bx              
LOOP cycle          

MOV byte ptr [bx], '$'

MOV ah, 9
MOV dx, offset symb
INT 21h

 terminate:
MOV ah, 4Ch         
MOV al, 0           
INT 21h         
END START
```

Just before the loop, cx has the number of symbols entered, and cycle begins to take pace from there on. This value of cx was obtained when variable "number" is copied to cl. How did variable "number" obtained such a value? Replacing

```
 MOV     cl, number
```

with

```
 MOV     cl, [number]
```

Does not effect the program. Why is that? Does every variable defined by

```
 variable   db ?
```

has the same value, i.e. number of symbols entered?(I am using TASM)

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: `int 21h/0Ah` is the well known "buffered input". You wrote it as `mov ah, 10` but it's the same interrupt. It requires a buffer with the first byte set to the maximum number of characters to enter (255 in your case), when the interrupt returns, the number of characters actually entered is put in the second byte of the buffer. The interrupt has altered your variable.